# .Net Framework 3.0 SP2 KB2756918 not installing

Tags: windows-server-2003, .net, patch-management

Ok, I'm about out of ideas here.  Can anyone help me with this .Net Framework Patch?  I am trying to install a KB patch (KB2756918) to a Windows Server 2003 R2 x86 box.

**Edit:** Just to clarify specs:
Windows Server 2003 R2 32 bit
Machines are on an *isolated* network
Manually installing patch (yes it is the 32 bit version)
Issue is affecting multiple boxes, but not all *(Both working & nonworking boxes are identical setups)*

For simpler reading I'm listing here what I've done first followed by the error I get, which incidentally, has never changed regardless of my troubleshooting steps.  (ie, it fails the same way every time; I'm not even getting different error messages)

*Please note this is on an isolated network*

**Trouble Shooting Steps:**  (I reboot and attempt a **manual** install after each troubleshooting step)

1. I have run a repair on .Net Framework (Fails due to isolated network)
2. I have manually uninstalled/reinstalled all versions of .Net
3. I have manually uninstalled all .Net versions
4. I have run the .Net removal tool on everything
5. I have run the .Net removal tool to get down to 3.0 so I can attempt to apply this patch & then apply the remaining .Net versions

So far, Technet & Google have been unfruitful endeavors

No matter what troubleshooting step I've completed I get the same installation error: ***"The installation failed with:  This package could not be opened..."***

**Event Viewer reports:**

1. ".NET Runtime Optimization Service (clr_optimization_v2.0.50727_32) - Service reached limit of transient errors. Will shut down. Last error returned from Service Manager: 0x80030002."
2. "The description for Event ID ( 0 ) in Source ( .NET Runtime ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: Shim database version ***(path location listed here was removed by me)*** doesn't have a matching runtime directory.

Comment: How are you getting the patch?  Specifically, have you tried manually downloading it and running that, or just been re-downloading via Windows Update?  (Oh, and one more stupid question... the Server you're trying to install this on *is* a 64 bit versions of Server 2003, right?)

Comment: Initially this was pushed using patch management software.  However, now that it's not working I have manually downloaded the patch from MS.  Also, not a dumb question as this is NOT a 64 bit.  I will edit the question to state it IS 32bit. Thanks

Comment: Alright, then here's the dumb question... you are downloading the 32 bit/x86 patch, right?  Named: `NDP30SP2-KB2756918-x86.exe`

Comment: Yes, I am using the x86 patch.  And I would say that is a dumb question except I completely understand your reason for asking. Thanks for checking, and in a nice, "I'm not calling you an idiot" way.

Comment: Have you tried the .Net Framework 3.5 SP1, I assume it would include the patch you trying to install above. http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=25150

Comment: Yes, 3.5 SP1 is installed on the server as well.  However, this patch is still required as it is new and not included in the SP.  (This patch was released in Jan 13)

Comment: Have you tried extracting it first and then running the MSP files one at a time. Or have you tried using .NET cleaner (http://goo.gl/gm9R0) to completely wipe out .NET from the system and then re-install it?

Comment: Try setting the DWORD value `State` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WinTrust\Trust Providers\Software Publishing` to the default, which is 0x22849.

Comment: @Kasius I just tried that but there is no change.  Same result with same error messages.

Comment: Okay.  An incorrect setting can prevent Windows from verifying the digital signature on the package, so I figured that might be related.  Have you tried the steps in [KB2549353](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2549353)?  It appears to be specifically related to your issue.

Comment: Originally No, I just ran the tool by itself.  I just did it though and it still gives me the same result.  TY for your help, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Kasius I found the answer and was able to fix it. I'll answer my own question below so if anyone else experiences the same issue they'll know how to fix it. But if you'll put all your comments into an answer I'll award you the bounty since you spent the most time trying to help me out (esp with new things that i hadn't yet tried.)  Thanks for all your help

Comment: @Kasius my offer still stands, if you put an answer below I'll award you the bounty since you are the one who put the most effort to help me answer this, but you have less than 1 hour to answer before the bounty expires

Comment: No, that's okay.  I'm not concerned with the bounty, since I didn't give the answer.  Glad you got it taken care of!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When all else fails: **READ THE DIRECTIONS!** *(yelling at myself here)*

On the Microsoft website for this KB Patch: (Under **Prerequisites**) *"To install this update, you must have **Windows Installer 3.1** or a **later** version installed on the computer. To obtain the latest version of Windows Installer..."*

**Background:** 
I can't even begin to tell you how much time/effort we spent on this problem.  And why on earth MS doesn't give you an error message that identifies an "outdated" MS Installer version is beyond me.  
We originally dismissed the Installer as the culprit because all other patches were installing fine.  To compound our confusion, was that multiple servers of identical build (which were supposedly identical in all ways) were split..some would take the patch and others would not.  For some reason this one particular patch/upgrade didn't apply to these select few servers.  Once we upgraded the installer everything worked like a champ!

So anyone having this or similar issues in the future, Check the prereqs and make sure you have the correct version of the MS installer.

Go into cmd prompt or the run dialog (Windows + R) and execute msiexec -?

Answer (score -1):

You need to wipe it completely out and start fresh with the entire framework. I know, painfully long downloads/installs await you, but it will get the job done.

Download:

http://cid-27e6a35d1a492af7.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Blog_Tools/dotnetfx_cleanup_tool.zip

Here's where it's from:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx

Run it and remove it all. Let it do it's thing, then reboot. Once you'e back in, proceed to reinstall the whole shabang, starting from 1.0/1.1 and up. I would just install up to 4.5, then recheck if the patch is still needed.

http://www.microsoft.com/net/download

Good luck!

EDIT: If you are reinstalling dotnet from cached copies somewhere, perhaps they are corrupt. Get a fresh copy from the microsoft link and try it out.

Comment: I have already attempted these steps listed as 4 & 5 above.  I didn't state it, but I did download a fresh copy of the KB just to make sure it wasn't corrupt.